# How to get identity (windows user) name for custom application pool in IIS

Tags: iis, identity, iis-8, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity

In IIS on Win Server 2016 Standard, I have created new application pool 'MyApplicationPool' with:

1. .NET CLR Version: none
2. Identity: ApplicationPoolIdentity

and configured non default website to use it.

However, when I try to use `IIS APPPOOL\MyApplicationPool` e.g. in folder security, it is not recognized..

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if we have already created the application pool in IIS, we could find it from the folder security.

Here is an example:

Server 2016:

[image]

I suggest you could recheck your application pool to make sure you have use the right application pool name.